# How to get all ref attribute values?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I `touch` an `entity` and get many entity ids. I want all the attribute values instead of the ids while keeping the nested structure.

```
(d/touch (d/entity (get-db) (ffirst (find-all-families))))
=> {:family/parent #{{:db/id 17592186045423}
                     {:db/id 17592186045424}
                     {:db/id 17592186045426}
                     {:db/id 17592186045427}},
    :family/child #{{:db/id 17592186045420}
                    {:db/id 17592186045421}},
    :family/address {:db/id 17592186045428},
    :family/email "someemail@gmail.com",
    :db/id 17592186045429}
```

Thought about using something like simply touching all the entity ids but seems like complexity creeps up if I want all of them:

```
(map d/touch (:family/parent (d/touch (d/entity (get-db) (ffirst (find-all-families))))))
```

Not sure what the idiomatic approach is: finding a way to do it more through the querying side or through clojure.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to do this in Datomic is to declare components in your schema. `touch` will touch all of the attributes of the entity, including any components recursively

Answer (score 0):

You will probably wish to use [the Datomic Pull API](http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html) for this purpose.  It can recursively return the attr/value pairs for all sub-entities that the user designates as "component".  An example:

```
  (def dark-side-of-the-moon [:release/gid #uuid "24824319-9bb8-3d1e-a2c5-b8b864dafd1b"])

  (d/pull db [:release/media] dark-side-of-the-moon)

  ; result 
  {:release/media
   [{:db/id 17592186121277,
     :medium/format {:db/id 17592186045741},
     :medium/position 1,
     :medium/trackCount 10,
     :medium/tracks
     [{:db/id 17592186121278,
       :track/duration 68346,
       :track/name "Speak to Me",
       :track/position 1,
       :track/artists [{:db/id 17592186046909}]}
      {:db/id 17592186121279,
       :track/duration 168720,
       :track/name "Breathe",
       :track/position 2,
       :track/artists [{:db/id 17592186046909}]}
      {:db/id 17592186121280,
       :track/duration 230600,
       :track/name "On the Run",
       :track/position 3,
       :track/artists [{:db/id 17592186046909}]}
      ...]}]}
```

You may also use [the Tupelo Datomic Pull API](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/datomic.adoc#using-the-datomic-pull-api), which I think is nicer.  As an example:

```
  ; If you wish to retain duplicate results on output, you must use td/query-pull and the Datomic
  ; Pull API to return a list of results (instead of a set).
  (let [result-pull     (td/query-pull  :let    [$ (live-db)]                 ; $ is the implicit db name
                                        :find   [ (pull ?eid [:location]) ]   ; output :location for each ?eid found
                                        :where  [ [?eid :location] ] )        ; find any ?eid with a :location attr
        result-sort     (sort-by #(-> % first :location) result-pull)
  ]
    (is (s/validate [ts/TupleMap] result-pull))    ; a list of tuples of maps
    (is (= result-sort  [ [ {:location "Caribbean"} ]
                          [ {:location "London"   } ]
                          [ {:location "London"   } ] ] )))
```